# Marker google maps android disappear when its not completely invisible

Tags: android, google-maps

I have big marker on google maps, Its disappear when its "should" not completely invisible as you can see in these picture below. It only happens when I move the camera up. I only move the camera up a little, all markers should still visible or half visible.

I thing its caused by google maps set the marker invisible when its not on camera, but google maps don't know that the marker is big and doesn't have same height with original google maps marker. Google maps pretend all marker is short so they disappear when its outside camera + marker size.

[image: this is when all markers are visible]

"Taman Biologi" is a infowindow of most left marker, the marker is disappear but its infowindow is still visible.

when the camera moved up:

[image: this is when i moved the camera up]

all markers should still visible or half visible.

What should i do with the map or marker to fix these problem while i want to show big marker on google maps?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been reported in our Public Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/35825847

To fix the problem, you can give this new release of the SDK (**Maps SDK for Android v.3.0.0 BETA**) a try by following the steps in our [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/v3-client-migration).

For more information on this release, you may refer to the full announcement on this [blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/whats-next-for-google-maps-platform). Hope this helps!